# Wordpress Website, page loading slows if I use a photo gallery plugin

Tags: wordpress, image, plugins, pageload, photography

My Wordpress Website pages load very slowly if I insert a photo gallery.

It's fine if I just put small photos on a page, but if I use a gallery plugin to save work the page takes ages to load.

I've been recommended NextGen gallery but the plugin insists I upgrade to a later Wordpress version. I've tried upgrading to the latest Wordpress version and latest theme version (Astra) but NextGen doesn't seem to work with those either. Essentially, if anyone knows a reliable way to display a photo gallery on Wordpress I would be very interested to hear.

Many thanks

Davey

Answer (score 0):

First, optimize your images .

Second, check site console after adding plugin.

Third, enable cache on site.